# Updating admin account info with PHP using adminSDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have to sync account information across 3 different platforms.  I wrote a password script that will update a users account information in LDAP, our Student Information System, and in gmail (for edu).  I had no issues with older migration api, but that is going away in the coming months.

I wrote a new library to use oauth2 and the adminSDK to manage my user accounts.  Im using a service account and specifying a superadmin account to preform account creations and password updates.  This  works perfectly fine with normal accounts.  However, it seems that I cannot reset my own password (Im an admin).

So far the things that my library can do are:  search, create, update, and delete NON-ADMIN accounts.  Things that do not work:  promote an account to admin, undelete an account, change admin account information (password for example).

Changing admin account info results in: "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" error.

Is there any way to get around this issue?  If not, this severely cripples my ability to use the new API to manage my users.  well, the admin users anyway.  I need it to work for all users, even the hand full of administrators.  I simply don'y see the point of a service account impersonating an admin, and then does not have all the proper rights to change account info on all accounts,  especially when the previous API allowed it.

please advise.

I can also provide my library for anyone interested in using it.

-Jerry

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the problem. I could edit the admin account's name successfully. Can you double check that you are using the right user ID  / email in the request?

Comment: I have verified that i cannot change admin account info with my class.  it works perfectly for changing non-admin accounts.  Im positive im using the correct ID/primaryEmail (ive tried both).  are you using the google provided php library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue.

When I started this project, I created a google account for this project and assigned it superadmin role.

I was revisiting my project today and I was getting the same errors when trying to update admin accounts.  I signed into the project's admin gmail account....  and accepted the terms...

now my library works perfectly.  yay.